# I am trying to Create this function in C++ and I am confused by the wording

Tags: c++

Requirements
You must create a function called searchLinkedList that searches a sorted linked list for a word and returns a pointer to the node containing the word (if found) or NULL.
This function must return NULL immediately after you pass the point in the linked list where the word would have been found if it was in the linked list.
The function takes three parameters:
char * searchWord (or you can use a string object): word to search for (entered by the user)
struct linkedList * linkedList: linked list to search (in your program, you can call the linked list node struct anything that makes sense)
int * comparisonCount: pointer to int filled in by the function with the count of strcmp comparisons done in searching the linked lis
Here is what I created.

```
WordNode* searchLinkedList(string searchedWord, WordNode* searchLinkedList, int* comparisonCount) {

    *comparisonCount = 0; 

    if (searchLinkedList == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error list\n";
    }

    while (searchLinkedList!=NULL) {

        if (searchLinkedList->word == searchedWord) {
            cout << "SUCCESS\n";
            cout << "Word was found:" << *comparisonCount; 
                break;
        }

        else {
            cout << "NOT there\n";
        }
        *comparisonCount++;
    }

    return searchLinkedList; 
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: If you are "confused by the wording", then why don't you ask the instructor who gave this assignment to you, for clarification? Irrespective of any other questions, `*comparisonCount++` is wrong, and is a bug.

Comment: At a glance it looks like your function will return correct values, but as Sam points out `*comparison++;` is performing `*(comparison++);` not `(*comparison)++;` which means you aren't correctly updating `*comparison`. You also aren't returning `NULL` as early as possible. The list is sorted, so you don't necessarily need to examine every single node to be sure that a given word isn't in it. If I'm searching for `"apple"` and have already reached a node containing the word `"cherry"`, do I need to keep looking?

Comment: as Nathan pointed out you should stop once you know for certain the Node is not in the list. You can compate ```std::string```s with the ```>``` operator

Comment: How can you " you can use a string object" if you have to return "the count of strcmp comparisons done in searching" ?  If you use a std::string do you really have to use .c_str() and strcmp to compare?  Also, why aren't the searchWord and the linkedList const?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you understand what the question is asking... iterate through the linked list in search of a specified word `searchWord` . As you do so, keep track of the amount of comparisons you make `comparisonCounter` and return the Node that matches. If for example, your linked list was `A->B->D->Z` and your searchWord was `C`, you would return `NULL` on the 3rd iteration, as the list is sorted and it should have been in between `B` and `D`.

```
WordNode* search(std::string searchWord, linkedList* l, int* comparisons) //instructions says a LinkedList is passed, so I assuming it has head variable...
{
   WordNode* temp = l->head;
   while(temp != NULL)
   {
      *comparisons = *comparisons + 1;
      if(temp->word == searchWord)
      {
         return temp;
      }
      else if(temp->word > searchWord) //lexicographical comparison by ASCII values
      {
         return NULL;
      }
      temp = temp->next;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```